# Universal density estimator

Tags: machine-learning, density-function, diffeomorphism

A Normalizing Flow is a powerful density estimator based on neural networks. Essentially, it is simply a chain of variable transforming the density to learn $p(x)$ into any target distribution (e.g. uniform or standard Gaussian)

In the paper ["Neural Autoregressive Flows"](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v80/huang18d/huang18d.pdf) by Huang et. al. the authors prove that their proposed flow is a universal density estimator in the sense that any density supported on an open set $U$ can be arbitrarily learned using their flow.

As the target distribution of the normalizing flow, they use a uniform distribution in $(0,1)^m$ where $m$ is the dimensionality of the data. However, $(0,1)^m$  is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$ such that the results still holds if one uses a standard Gaussian target distribution instead of uniform. But this is a contradiction, as not every open set is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$, see e.g. [discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4468/what-are-the-open-subsets-of-mathbbrn-that-are-diffeomorphic-to-mathbbr).

So how is it possible that at the one hand not every open set $U$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$, but at the other hand a density supported on any open set $U$ can be learned using a normalizing flow?